# Не обновляется страница после изменения стейта в redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

Проблема с асинхронным запросом. Должно работать так: при запуске происходит запрос фоток на сервере, стартуем экшен (fetchPhotosRequestAC), который меняет статус в стейте isLoaded на false. Компонента видит этот false и выдаёт сообщение "Фотографии загружаются..."
Когда данные пришли, запускаем новый экшен (fetchPhotosSuccessAC), в него передаём полученные данные. В редюсере данные записываются в стейт, а флаг меняется на isLoaded = true. Типа, "компонента, смотри, данные загрузились, возьми их из стейта и отрисуйся заново". Но ничего не происходит, компонента не обновляется.

Компонента:

```html
import React from 'react';
import s from './Main.module.scss';
import Unsplash, {toJson} from 'unsplash-js';
import {fetchPhotosRequestAC, fetchPhotosSuccessAC} from '../../redux/reducer';

function Main (props) {
  const unsplash = new Unsplash ({
    accessKey: props.state.security.ACCESS_KEY,
    secret: props.state.security.SECRET,
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/auth',
  });

  props.dispatch (fetchPhotosRequestAC ());

  const p = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    // Просим сервер прислать нам котиков
    unsplash.search.photos ('cats', 1).then (toJson).then (json => {
      let serverData = json;
      resolve (serverData);
    });
  });

  // Когда котики получены
  p.then (serverData => {
    props.dispatch (fetchPhotosSuccessAC (serverData));
  });

  // debugger;

  return (
    <div className={s.main__wrapper}>
      {console.log (props.state.isLoaded)}
      {props.state.isLoaded
        ? props.state.serverData.results.map ((el, i) => (
            <img
              id={el.id}
              src={el.urls.full}
              alt={el.alt_description}
              key={i}
            />
          ))
        : <p>Фотографии загружаются...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Reducer (упрощённый):

```html
// action names
const FETCH_PHOTOS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_PHOTOS_REQUEST';
const FETCH_PHOTOS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_PHOTOS_SUCCESS';

// actions
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PHOTOS_REQUEST: {
      state.isLoaded = false;
      return state;
    }

    case FETCH_PHOTOS_SUCCESS: {
      state.isLoaded = true;
      state.serverData = action.serverData;
      return state;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const fetchPhotosRequestAC = () => ({type: FETCH_PHOTOS_REQUEST});
export const fetchPhotosSuccessAC = serverData => ({
  type: FETCH_PHOTOS_SUCCESS,
  serverData,
});

export default reducer;
```

Comment: может в `useEffect` засунуть всё до `return`

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить, что проблема здесь:

```
state.serverData = action.serverData;
```

Я бы попробовал в этом месте делать копию `state`

Comment: return {...state} попробовал и несколько других способов. Вы это имеете в виду? Не помогает. Повторно отрисовка DOM не происходит. Я, наверное, что-то элементарное упускаю. Несколько дней уже не могу решить эту проблему. Был бы рад любому, даже общему совету, куда можно посмотреть ещё.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, что именно Вы имеете в виду. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку сам. Нелепая, как часто и бывает. Я не добавил функцию ререндера в редакс (store.subscribe), скорее всего случайно затёр в ходе экспериментов. Вопрос закрыт.